# How to do code analysis on ASP.NET MVC 3 view files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-analysis

How to do code analysis on code written in ASPX / ASCX files in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application? Is it possible to create custom rules which can inspect code written in "<%= %>" or "<%: %>" or "<% %>" code blocks? The ASPX / ASCX files in this context are views or partial views in ASP.NET MVC 3 context.

Answer (score 0):

Code analysis is usually performed on server side logic code. Such code should never be written in a view thus no need to perform code analysis there. For views spitting HTML the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is a good tool to analyze the code.

The `<%:` and `<%=` are just calls to helper methods whose logic is implemented on the server so they should be analyzed in the server code. As far as the `<%` is concerned if I were to write a code analysis tool for views I would put as rule inside it that `<%` is not present in a view because this assumes the developer wrote a server side code in a view which as I stated shouldn't be done.

Comment: One particular rule that I would like to enforce on views is that when Html.* is used, the data entry labels being rendered should come from resource files and should not be hard-coded. I was hoping for finding a way of identifying all Html.* calls in views and then build a rule to ensure usage of resource files.

Comment: @Dhwanil Shah, I am not sure I understand your question.